# set some view variable in controller constructer

Tags: zend-view, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I have the following code in my zf2 controller:

```
<?php
namespace Accounting\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController,
Zend\View\Model\ViewModel,
Accounting\Model,
Zend\Paginator,
Accounting\Scripts\CMSTranslator;

class AdminController extends ActionController {

protected $translator;

public function setTranslator(CMSTranslator $translator) {
    $this->translator = $translator;
    return $this;
}

public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em,CMSTranslator $translator) {
    $this->em = $em;

    //$this->translator = new \Zend\Translator\Translator('ArrayAdapter', __DIR__ . '/../../../lang/lang-fa.php', 'fa');
    $this->translator = $translator;

    \Zend\Registry::set('tr', $this->translator);
    // now you can use the EntityManager!
}
```

As you can see I'm using the zend\translator module.
I want to add it to the view in my controller constructor.
I already tried:

```
return ViewModel(array('tr'=>$translator));
```

But that doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: By the way, there shouldn't really be any reason to use \Zend\Registry - objects you put in the registry are essentially global variables, which isn't good form. Instead of using the registry, why not use DI to configure your Translator and inject it where ever it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final solution module.config.php

```
'Accounting\Controller\AccountingController' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'em' => 'doctrine_em',
                'translator' => 'Accounting\Scripts\CMSTranslator',
            ),
        ),
        'Zend\View\Helper\Translator' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'translator' => 'Accounting\Scripts\CMSTranslator'
            )
        ),
        'Accounting\Scripts\CMSTranslator' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'options' => array('adapter' => 'ArrayAdapter', 'content' => __DIR__ . '/../lang/lang-fa.php', 'local' => 'fa')
            )
        ),
        'translateAdapter' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'options' => array('adapter' => 'ArrayAdapter', 'content' => __DIR__ . '/../lang/lang-fa.php', 'local' => 'fa')
            )
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

add a private class variable `private $viewModel`. Then create the ViewModel in your construtor, add any variables:

```
$this->viewModel = new ViewModel();
$this->viewModel->tr = $translator;
```

Then return `$this->viewModel` from your action function.

Comment: thanks  can you plz look @ this issue https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/37